# To what degree does Vados say Kale and Caulifla's power increases when fused?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super, japanese-language

In this video with Spanish subtitles about Kefura's fight vs Goku, Vados says:

> her power (the power of Kale and Caulifla fused) isn't the double, it is at least ten times bigger.

[Video 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JSnjm2I0-U0)

However, in this other video with english subtitles, about Kefura's fight vs Goku, Vados says:

> .. and their power increases tens of times.

[Video 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sifsLXZlYMs)

What did Vados truly say in the original Japanese dialogue? Is it what the Spanish subtitles say or is it what the English subtitles say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Vados said was:

> **数{すう}十{じゅう}倍{ばい}にも膨{ふく}れ上{あ}がります** *(Sū jū bai ni mo fukureagari masu)*

which literally means **(something) will expand tens of times**.

Comment: I have other questions about japanese here, can you answer them?

Comment: @Pablo Sure go ahead. I will do my best.

Comment: I mean, as questions here in anime SE https://anime.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:3028+[japanese-language]

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be pointed out that what Vados said is completely inaccurate and was a flaw from the writers contradicting facts stated before and what Vados said can easily be debunked. Vados stated that the transformation made the fusion (several 10s of times stronger), which absolutely doesn't make sense. As this would imply that the fusion is even weaker than SSJ2 Caulfila because it has been confirmed that the SSJ2 transformation is beyond a 100 times stronger and Kale's transformation is significantly stronger than SSJ2 as we see her going toe to toe with Super Saiyan God Goku while Caulifla is completely outclassed.

Comment: In both cases the multiplier could be a huge number. The only difference is that if she said, "at least 10 times" it could be not only a huge number but a not so big number like 11,12. If she actually said "tens of times" then it has to be at least 20 but it could be also 1 million

Comment: What Vados said is incorrect the multiplier is way more bigger. The actual translation is (Several 10s of times stronger). If the potara fusion is several 10s of times stronger how exactly this base vegito humuliate Buu Han?(Super Buu+Ultimate Gohan). For the record, "Several 10s, doesn't imply 1 million" lol

Comment: if you are sure the actual translation from japanese is "several 10s of times stronger" then post that as an answer because that is what the question was about, regardless if what Vados says it is contradictory with other parts of the series or not

Comment: Firstly I did post the same. Secondly, if you were interested to know what precisely were Vados words, that would imply you were interested in the content. Hence I also pointed out that the content was inaccurate.